# Angularjs form validation input field without name

Tags: forms, angularjs, validation

How to track input field validation within form without using field name or field name as array e.g. user[user_name]?

Sample Code:

```
<div ng-class="{ 'has-error' : saveUserForm.user[first_name].$invalid && !saveUserForm.user[first_name].$pristine }">
   <input type="text" value="{{userAttr.first_name}}" required ng-model="userAttr.first_name" name="user[first_name]" id="inputFirstName">
</div>
```

Using array name "user[first_name]" for form field is not working, and I can not change it to simple name like "firstName".

Can I use id of the field "inputFirstName" here: saveUserForm.inputFirstName.$invalid ?

Comment: BTW it is ng-model.
But I don't want to track its value, I need to track if the field is valid or not so that I can add error class to the field 
e.g. ng-class="{error: userForm.userName.$invalid}"

Comment: Show some code, of what you are trying.

Comment: @Chandermani Please refer updated code sample above.

Comment: Name is required as it is used to create ngModelController. Also i don't think you can give an expression in the name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name attribute is required*, but Angular is not peeky about the name. It is OK if the name is `user[first_name]`, as long as it is referenced correctly.

Assuming a name like this: `name="user[first_name]"`
You should reference it like this: `saveUserForm['user[first_name]'].$...`

E.g.

```
<div ng-class="{'has-error':saveUserForm['user[first_name]'].$invalid&&
                            !saveUserForm['user[first_name]'].$pristine}">
```

See, also, this **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/269hS/)**.

---

A little explanation:
In JavaScript `saveUserForm.user[first_name]`
is equivalent to `a[b]`
where `a = saveUserForm.user` 
and `b = first_name`

---

<sub>*: You might be able to get away with using no name, by creating a custom directive, get hold of the parent form's `FormController` and add the elements using its **[`$addControl()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController#%24addControl)** method, but there is really no need to.</sub>

Comment: Hey. Is there is any way to validate form without using name attribute. I don't know, if I add name="objectvo.fieldname", by default I am getting [object object].

Comment: I have already answered your question in my answer :)If you face any specific issue, please post a question.